# Does using the Overpass polygon query have a computational advantage over a bounding box?

Tags: overpass-api

For a project on geospatial data analytics, we are currently extracting road type and speed limit data of certain roads along a track by using Overpass' polygon query (where we define the roads by a buffer zone around them). The problem is that in the case of separate tracks, we can end up with disconnected polygons which often lead to a significant increase in computation time. In this situation, we were wondering how Overpass' polygon query actually works. Does the algorithm actually query only the data inside this polygon/these polygons, or does it query inside a bounding box, after which it filters out the data inside the polygons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm checks if nodes are inside the defined polygon, or if a way crosses the polygon. It's not based on bounding boxes as you mentioned.

From your description it's not quite clear why disconnected polygons pose an issue. You should get decent performance with a lz4-based backend and a reasonable number of lat/lon pairs in your `(poly: )` filter (the more pairs you provide, the more expensive the computation gets).

BTW: The best approach to tackle this issue would be something I described in this blog post: https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/mmd/diary/42055 - unfortunately, this feature is not yet available in the official branch. If you see some use for it, please upvote here: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/418